# Query for Customers, total value of purchases, and total discounts given to Customers by Year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I using the Northwind database. I wanted to write a query that displays the Customers, total value of purchases, and total discounts given to Customers by the Year. I wanted to show all Customers for the year 1996, 1997, 1998.

Down below are the tables I am using.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [CustomerID]
      ,[CompanyName]
      ,[ContactName]
      ,[ContactTitle]
      ,[Address]
      ,[City]
      ,[Region]
      ,[PostalCode]
      ,[Country]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[Fax]
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers]

SELECT TOP (1000) [OrderID]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[EmployeeID]
      ,[OrderDate]
      ,[RequiredDate]
      ,[ShippedDate]
      ,[ShipVia]
      ,[Freight]
      ,[ShipName]
      ,[ShipAddress]
      ,[ShipCity]
      ,[ShipRegion]
      ,[ShipPostalCode]
      ,[ShipCountry]
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]

SELECT TOP (1000) [OrderID]
      ,[ProductID]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Discount]
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details]
```

Here is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT  o.customerID, year(o.OrderDate) as Year,
        sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) as Total_value_of_purchase, 
        sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * od.Discount) as Total_discount_received,
        sum((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity)-(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * od.Discount)) as Total_after_discount
FROM Customers as c
cross JOIN Orders as o

left outer join [Order Details] as od
on o.OrderID=od.OrderID

GROUP BY o.CustomerID, Year(o.OrderDate)
order by o.CustomerID, Year(o.OrderDate)
```

Here is the picture of the result I got.

[image]

You can notice that, in some cases, customers might not have ordered in every year, so I only got 234 results. Is there is any way I can display all customers and all 3 years? so if I have 91 customers, the result would show 91*3=273 result.

Can you please provide me with a guideline or some help, so I can follow to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

I have some update. I tried using union.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, y.YR,
        sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) as Total_value_of_purchase, 
        sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * od.Discount) as Total_discount_received,
        sum((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity)-(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity * od.Discount)) as Total_after_discount
FROM (SELECT 1996 YR UNION ALL SELECT 1997 UNION ALL SELECT 1998) y(YR)
CROSS JOIN Customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, y.YR
ORDER BY c.CustomerID, y.YR
```

The result: https://ibb.co/N9T7pk2

I did get 273 results, but instead of giving me the total for each year, it gave me the total for all years.

Any suggestions?

PS: I am not doing this for the assignment. I am genuinely interested in finding the solution.